# Ocelot microgateway hosted in IIS

Tags: asp.net-core, ocelot

Hi I was trying to implement ocelot for our experimental tests on dev.
Here is end-point of api that I want to reach by via ocelot. using 443 port for both of project.
but getting 502 bad gateway all the time.

end point => https://localhost/document/api/v1/Documents/XYZ

```
  "ReRoutes": [
{
  "DownstreamPathTemplate": "/document/api/v1/Documents/{name}",
  "DownstreamScheme": "https",
  "DownstreamHostAndPorts": [
    {
      "Host": "localhost",
      "Port": 443
    }
  ],
  "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/apigateway/{name}/document",
  "UpstreamHttpMethod": [ "Post" ],
  "Priority": 0
}
```

],
"GlobalConfiguration": {
"BaseUrl": "https://localhost:443"
}
}

Microgateway alias name =>"apigateway"
Api alias name => "document"

In addition this I was able to debug on visiual studio but whenever I host both app on my local IIS getting 502 bad gateway

Comment: It's most probably some issue with the configuration. Are you sure it's hosted on https port 443 ?

Comment: Hi I hosted on 443 on iss thats for sure

Comment: Does 443 work when you try connecting to it directly?

Comment: Yup it's hitting the API. I think it might also be related to the way of published API.

Comment: Hi @OguzBerkayYerdelen, I am also facing a similar issue when I host in IIS. Is your issue resolved now?

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the configuration you have used is redirecting the request to the gateway itself, resulting in a circle.

i.e. the upstream call to the base URL of "localhost:443" is redirecting to the downstream "localhost:443" - the same.

Furthermore, the later versions of Ocelot appear to look for `Routes` in the configuration instead of `ReRoutes` [documentation](https://ocelot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/features/routing.html)